# CSS style to an HTML element based on ng-model value

Tags: html, css, .net, angularjs

I started programming with AngularJS and my first project is a Sudoku solver.
If a user writes a value into a input box, i want to validate that value.
A value is valid if the rules of the game hold (each row,col and 2x3 box contain the digits from 1 to 6 only once).
If the value is invalid, i want to make the border of the input element red.

**SudokuController.js:**

```
 (function (angular) {

SudokuController.$inject = ['$scope'];
function SudokuController($scope) {
    function Cell(row, column) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }
    //initialize out sudoku puzzle object
    $scope.puzzle = {};
    $scope.puzzle.dimensions = 6;
    $scope.puzzle.board = [$scope.puzzle.dimensions];
    $scope.puzzle.moves = [];

    $scope.initialize = function () {
            //initialize the gameboard with empty values
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.puzzle.dimensions; i++) {
                $scope.puzzle.board[i] = [$scope.puzzle.dimensions];
                for (var j = 0; j < $scope.puzzle.dimensions; j++) {
                    $scope.puzzle.board[i][j] = undefined;
                }
            }
            initialized = true;
        }

    //other functions:
}

angular
    .module('sudokuApp')
    .controller('SudokuController', SudokuController);})(window.angular);
```

**Layout.cshtml**

```
    <div ng-controller="SudokuController" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <form role="form" class="center-block" style="width: 1100px; height: 200px; margin-top:100px;">
                <div ng-repeat="row in [0,1,2,3,4,5]" class="row solverrow ">
                    <div ng-repeat="column in [0,1,2,3,4,5]" class="col-sm-1 nopadding {{ row | rowFilter }} {{ column | columnFilter }} ">
                        <input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
                               type="number" maxlength="1" class="form-control text-center" ng-model="puzzle.board[row][column]"
                                name="cell[]">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="row angmenu">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="initialize()">Initialize</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-generate" ng-click="generate()">Generate new board</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="solve()">Solve</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So basically what i want is to check the new typed value with the values already typed in the relevant row,col and box and to dynamically change the border if the value is invalid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to wrap your input filed with a span to which you can assign a CSS class, indicating an error. E.g. `<span ng-class="{'has-error' : puzzle.board[row][column]>6 || puzzle.board[row][column]<=0}">`

Comment: it works if i assign ng-class to the input element but it does not work if i apply the class to a span element wrapping my input element. Anyway thanks for the answer!